# Python pickle with complex classes

Tags: python, windows, class, service, pickle

I am developing a windows service to monitor signal from a control system. I have modeled the system with two classes (IOSignal and Control). Every Control instance has some IOSignals instances associated with it. When all IOSignals associated with a specific control are in a specific state I want that the service do something. In my real code it will register this event in a database. To explain my problem I created a very simplified version o my original code. 
The problem is that as it runs as a service I want to store the states of all Control and IOSignal instances so when I restart the service I can "remember" the state of my system when it stopped. I am using pickle to do that. It seems that the pickling part is working as apparently I can open the file in another script and retrieve the information of my objects. 
The complication of my system is that I have IOSignals instances stored in every Control object and the other way round.
When I star the service is seems to work fine but when I restart it I start receiving error messages that the recreated object do not have some attributes (mainly 'd' and 'logger')
I have overloades the **getstae** and **setstate** methods to try to make pickle works but I think that I am missing something. I followed the instructions given in this python documentation (https://docs.python.org/2.0/lib/pickle-example.html)

Here is the code of my Classes (I save them in a file called Observer.py)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Wed Aug  2 11:07:28 2017

@author: me
"""
from logging import getLogger
#import logging

class IOSignal(object):

    def __init__(self,tag,val='True'):
        self.tag=tag
        self.value=val
        self.CONTROLS=[]

        #logger
        self.logger=getLogger('teste.IOSignals')

        # dict to serialize 
        self.d={}
        self.d['tag']=self.tag
        self.d['value']=self.value
        self.d['CONTROLS']=self.CONTROLS

    def getTag(self):
        return self.tag

    def getValue(self):
        return self.value

    def UpdateIOSinal(self,val):
        self.value=val
        try:
            for control in self.CONTROLS:
                #self.logger.debug('updating controls')
                control.update()
        except Exception as e:
               self.logger.error("Error updating signal - ErrMsg -> {}".format(str(e)))

    def AppendControl(self,control):
        self.CONTROLS.append(control)

    def UpdateControls(self):
        for control in self.CONTROLS:
            control.update()

    def __getstate__(self):
        return self.d

    def __setstate__(self, d):
        self.tag=d['tag']
        self.value=d['value']
        self.CONTROLS=d['CONTROLS']
        self.__dict__= d


class Control(object):

    def __init__(self,tag,state=False):
         self.tag=tag
         self.state=state
         self.IOSignals={}

         #logger
         self.logger=getLogger('teste.CONTROLS')

         # dict to serialize 
         self.d={}
         self.d['tag']=self.tag
         self.d['state']=self.state
         self.d['IOSignals']=self.IOSignals


    def getTag(self):
        return self.tag

    def getState(self):
        return self.state

    def register_signal(self,signal):
        self.IOSignals[len(self.IOSignals)]=signal

    def update(self):
        try:
            I=len([e.value for e in self.IOSignals.values() if e.value=='False'])
            if I==len(self.IOSignals):
                self.logger.info("Control {} actuated".format(self.tag))
        except Exception as e:
               self.logger.error("Error updating Contro - ErrMsg -> {}".format(str(e)))

    def __getstate__(self):
        return self.d

    def __setstate__(self, d):
        self.tag=d['tag']
        self.state=d['state']
        self.IOSignals=d['IOSignals']

        self.__dict__= d
```

and here is the code to create the service and use Observer. I called it teste_service.py
to install it type in a command line the following command "python c:\pathtofile\teste_service.py install" and put it run in Windows Services.
The name of the service is TEST_Event_Service.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Thu Jul 27 09:07:29 2017

@author: me
"""

from Observer import IOSignal
from Observer import Control
import os
import threading
import logging
import logging.config
import win32api
import win32service
import win32serviceutil
import win32event
import random
import time
import pickle

class InterruptedException(Exception):
    pass

class WorkerThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, controller,dCONFIG):
        self._controller = controller
        self._stop = threading.Event()
        super(WorkerThread, self).__init__()

        self.dCONFIG=dCONFIG
        self.dIO=dCONFIG['dIO']
        self.dCTRL=dCONFIG['dCTRL']

        #logger
        self.logger=logging.getLogger('teste.SERVICE')

    def stop(self):
        self._stop.set()

    def stopped(self):
        return self._stop.isSet()

    def saveCACHE(self):
        try:
           f=open(r'C:\TIER3\teste\teste.pkl','wb')
           pickle.dump(self.dCONFIG,f,protocol=4)
           f.close()
        except Exception as e:
           self.logger.error("Error saving cache - ErrMsg -> {}".format(str(e)))

    def getCONFIG(self):
        return self.dCONFIG

    def run(self):
        try:
           # simulater signal state based on a random number generator
           for signal in self.dIO.values():
               r=random.random()
               if r>0.5:
                   signal.UpdateIOSinal('False')
               else:
                   signal.UpdateIOSinal('True')

           #updating dCONFIG to pickle it
           self.dCONFIG['dIO']=self.dIO
           self.dCONFIG['dCTRL']=self.dCTRL

           try:
               self.saveCACHE()
           except Exception as e:
               self.logger.error("Error saving cache - ErrMsg -> {}".format(str(e)))

           #self.logger.info('run finished')
           time.sleep(10)
        except InterruptedException as e:
           # We are forcefully quitting 
           self.logger.error('Interruption Exception - {}'.format(str(e)))
           pass
        except Exception as e:
            self.logger.error('Unexpected Error - {}'.format(str(e)))
            #self.logger.error(e)
            pass
           # Oh oh, did not anticipate this, better report to Windows or log it
        finally:
            #pass
           # Close/release any connections, handles, files etc.
           # OK, we can stop now
            win32event.SetEvent(self._controller)

class test_service(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):

   _svc_name_ = "pyTEST"
   _svc_display_name_ = "TEST Event service"
   _svc_description_ = "Service to teste python service"

   def __init__(self, args):
       win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, args)
       self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)     
       self.hWaitDone = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)
       self.dCONFIG={}
       #------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       # Creating logger
       #------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       logging.config.fileConfig(r'c:\tier3\teste\teste_logging.conf')
       # create logger
       self.logger = logging.getLogger('teste')

       self.logger.info(self._svc_name_ + " - STARTED!")
       #creating some IOSignals and Controls
       dIO={}
       dCTRL={}
       try:
           if os.path.exists(r'C:\TIER3\teste\teste.pkl'):
               f=open(r'C:\TIER3\teste\teste.pkl','rb')
               self.dCONFIG=pickle.load(f)
               dIO=self.dCONFIG['dIO']
               dCTRL=self.dCONFIG['dCTRL']
               f.close()            
           else:
               dIO[1]=IOSignal('IO1')
               dIO[2]=IOSignal('IO2')
               dIO[3]=IOSignal('IO3')
               dIO[4]=IOSignal('IO4')
               dIO[5]=IOSignal('IO5')
               dIO[6]=IOSignal('IO6')
               dIO[7]=IOSignal('IO7')        
               dIO[8]=IOSignal('IO8')

               dCTRL[1]=Control('CTRL1')
               dCTRL[2]=Control('CTRL2')
               dCTRL[3]=Control('CTRL3')
               dCTRL[4]=Control('CTRL4')

               dIO[1].AppendControl(dCTRL[1])
               dIO[2].AppendControl(dCTRL[1])
               dIO[3].AppendControl(dCTRL[2])
               dIO[4].AppendControl(dCTRL[2])
               dIO[5].AppendControl(dCTRL[3])
               dIO[6].AppendControl(dCTRL[3])
               dIO[7].AppendControl(dCTRL[4])
               dIO[8].AppendControl(dCTRL[4])

               dCTRL[1].register_signal(dIO[1])
               dCTRL[1].register_signal(dIO[2])
               dCTRL[2].register_signal(dIO[3])
               dCTRL[2].register_signal(dIO[4])
               dCTRL[3].register_signal(dIO[5])
               dCTRL[3].register_signal(dIO[6])
               dCTRL[4].register_signal(dIO[7])
               dCTRL[4].register_signal(dIO[8])

               self.dCONFIG={}
               self.dCONFIG['dIO']=dIO
               self.dCONFIG['dCTRL']=dCTRL

       except Exception as e:
           self.logger.error("Error opening teste.pkl - ErrMsg -> {}".format(str(e)))

   def SvcStop(self):
       self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
       win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)

   def SvcDoRun(self):
        import servicemanager      
        servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,
                              servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTED,(self._svc_name_, '')) 

        #create worker 1st run
        self.worker = WorkerThread(self.hWaitDone,self.dCONFIG)
        self.worker.setDaemon=True
        self.worker.start()

        while True:
            rc = win32event.WaitForMultipleObjects([self.hWaitStop, self.hWaitDone],False,win32event.INFINITE)
            #self.logger.debug('rc = {}'.format(rc))
            # Check to see if self.hWaitStop happened as part of Windows Service Management
            if rc == 0:
                # Stop signal encountered
                self.logger.info(self._svc_name_ + " - STOPPED!")
                servicemanager.LogInfoMsg(self._svc_name_ + " - STOPPED!")  #For Event Log
                break
            if rc == 1:
                #create worker
                self.dCONFIG=self.worker.getCONFIG()
                self.worker = WorkerThread(self.hWaitDone,self.dCONFIG)
                self.worker.setDaemon=True
                self.worker.start()

def ctrlHandler(ctrlType):
   return True

if __name__ == '__main__':   
   win32api.SetConsoleCtrlHandler(ctrlHandler, True)   
   win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(test_service)
```

here is the logging set

```
[loggers]
keys=root,teste

[handlers]
keys=logfile,consoleHandler

[formatters]
keys=simpleFormatter,logfileformatter

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler

[logger_teste]
level=DEBUG
handlers=logfile
qualname=teste
propagate=0

[formatter_logfileformatter]
format=%(asctime)s %(name)-12s: %(levelname)s %(message)s

[formatter_simpleFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s
datefmt=

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[handler_logfile]
class=handlers.RotatingFileHandler
level=DEBUG
args=(r'C:\tier3\teste\pyteste.log','a',5000000,20)
formatter=logfileformatter
```

I think that my problem is in the **getstate** and **setstate** definitions.

here is a sample of the error messages I receive.

```
2017-08-02 22:58:00,348 teste.SERVICE: ERROR Error saving cache - ErrMsg -> 'IOSignal' object has no attribute 'd'
2017-08-02 22:58:10,366 teste.SERVICE: ERROR Unexpected Error - 'IOSignal' object has no attribute 'logger'
```

Anyone has some ideia where is my problem?

Comment: There are many things that can't be pickled. That's probably what is happening

Comment: Yes. I know that but if a unpickle the file in the python console I can see that the structure of class are retrieved. I can call the methods and access the instances attributes. But, in some way, the instance reconstruction is not complete and some items are left behind.

Comment: Change to `self.__dict__.update(d)`.

Comment: It didn't have any effect.

Comment: Did you check if it has `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` methods? That is what pickle uses to save object state.

Comment: Yes. I did. As I told above it seems that the classes instances are saved with all methods but when the service try to run the next pickle operation it fails.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution that is not ellegant as I would like. As the instances are not been recreated perfectly I am creating all the instances every time the service is running and check if there is a cache file. If there is I adjust the instances states with the information from cache. Here is the modified code of Observer.py. I created new methods to set the values I need.